# Replace characters in a string (automating filter conditions) - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The work is to parameterize filter conditions in a query so user can choose the filter conditions on the fly and query will be generated.
There are 3 columns in the table and col2 has filter value and col3 has AND/OR filter conditions. Please help me out.

```
col1    col2           col3
------------------------------

v1      sal1 > 10

v2      sal2 > 500  

v3                     v1 OR v2  (comments :  col2 is NULL, col3 is v1 OR v2)

v4                     v1 AND v2  (comments :  col2 is NULL, col3 is v1 AND v2)

v5                     v3 AND v6  (comments:  col2 is NULL, col3 is v1 AND v2)

v6  amt > 20
```

---

when v3 is selected

```
v3  (sal1> 10 OR sal2 > 500)
```

when v4 is selected

```
v4  (sal1> 10 AND sal2 > 500)
```

when v5 is selected

```
v5  ((sal1> 10 OR sal2 > 500) AND amt > 20)
```

---

Have attached sample script and it will use dynamic SQL to generate the SQL based on user selection.

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_2
(
 COL1 VARCHAR2(4000),
 COL2 VARCHAR2(4000),
 COL3 VARCHAR2(4000)
 );

insert into TEST_2 values ('v1', 'sal1 > 10', null);
insert into TEST_2 values ('v2', 'sal2 > 500', null);
insert into TEST_2 values ('v3', null, 'v1 OR v2');
insert into TEST_2 values ('v4', null, 'v1 AND v2');
insert into TEST_2 values ('v5', null, 'v3 AND v6');
insert into TEST_2 values ('v6', 'amt > 20', null);
commit;


col1    col2        col3
v1      sal1 > 10   
v2      sal2 > 500  
v3                  v1 OR v2
v4                  v1 AND v2
v5                  v3 AND v6
v6  amt > 20
```

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text please, no images.

Comment: Run away from this as fast as you can. "Frenkenstein's monster" is what comes to mind, seeing this approach to generating queries on the fly.

Comment: Dynamic SQL comes to mind ...

Comment: You mean "when **v5** is selected"

`((sal1> 10 OR sal2 > 500) AND amt > 20)`. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Oracle 11g...sorry for the typo..yes when v5 is selected it has to be ((sal1> 10 OR sal2 > 500) AND amt > 20)

Comment: Ok, this requires a recursive parser. Difficult with PL/2. I can give you a C# solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a C# solution using Regex to build a recursive parser. I created a class `QueryTemplate` which stores the contents of your table.

```
public class QueryTemplate
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public string Expression { get; set; }
}
```

As test setup, I initialize data like this:

```
private Dictionary<string, QueryTemplate> _templates;

public void Test()
{
    _templates = new Dictionary<string, QueryTemplate> {
        ["v1"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v1", Term = "sal1 > 10" },
        ["v2"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v2", Term = "sal2 > 500" },
        ["v3"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v3", Expression = "v1 OR v2" },
        ["v4"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v4", Expression = "v1 AND v2" },
        ["v5"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v5", Expression = "v3 AND v6" },
        ["v6"] = new QueryTemplate { Id = "v6", Term = "amt > 20" },
    };

   Console.WriteLine(CreateSqlCondition("v5"));
}
```

Console output:

> ((sal1 > 10) OR (sal2 > 500)) AND (amt > 20)

The condition is built recursively like this:

```
public string CreateSqlCondition(string id)
{
    if (_templates.TryGetValue(id, out QueryTemplate qt)) {
        if (qt.Term != null) {
            return qt.Term;
        } else { // Expression
            // Assuming that all Ids start with "v", but not column names.
            var idMatches = Regex.Matches(qt.Expression, @"\bv\w+\b");
            string expr = qt.Expression;
            foreach (var match in idMatches.Cast<Match>().Reverse()) {
                // Replace in reverse order to preserve the match positions.
                string idName = match.Value;
                string cond = CreateSqlCondition(idName);
                string prefix = (expr.Substring(0, match.Index));
                string suffix = expr.Substring(match.Index + match.Length);
                expr = $"{prefix}({cond}){suffix}";
            }
            return expr;
        }
    } else {
        throw new ArgumentException($"Query template \"{id}\" not found.");
    }
}
```

I also add parentheses around each term to preserve the priority of the AND/OR operators.

A problem is to distinguish between IDs and column names. Maybe you should use Id names like $1, $2, $3 ... to avoid confusions. Also, Using only one column for both, terms and expressions, would allow you to combine Ids and column names. Example (using "$" ids): `$5 AND amt <= 20`. Of course my `CreateSqlCondition` method would have to be adapted for that.

The regex expression `\bv\w+\b` means

```
\b     word boundary (beginning of word)
v      the character v  
\w+    all following word characters (letters, digits and underscores)  
\b     word boundary (end of word)
```

If you choose to use "$" instead of "v", escape it with "\":

```
@"\b\$\w+\b"
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did this for fun, because I've never implemented a [binary expression tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) in SQL. But it'll only lead you to suffering further down the road.

```
select listagg(dyn_where) within group (order by bintree_order) as dynamic_where from
(select c.*, rpad(c.syspath, max(lvl) over (), '1') as bintree_order from (
    select level as lvl, 
           replace(sys_connect_by_path(case when sign(nvl(instr(prior col3, col1)-floor(length(prior col3)/2),0)) <= 0 then '0' else '2' end, ' '), ' ') as syspath,
           col2 || substr(col3, 3, length(col3)-4) as dyn_where
    from TEST_2
    connect by instr(prior col3, col1) > 0  
    start with col1 = 'v5'
    ) c 
);
```

This query currently depends on col1 being 2 characters long (for doing a substr on col3). This wouldn't be necessary if you changed your table structure to split up `COL3` into 3 columns - one for the first operand, one for the boolean operator (e.g. OR), and one for the second operand. In this example, col3 and col5 could actually be foreign keys to col1, and you'd have a much easier time. Ha, relatively. Still a bad idea. :)

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_2
(
 COL1 VARCHAR2(4000), -- primary key
 COL2 VARCHAR2(4000), -- binary tree leaf node value
 COL3 VARCHAR2(4000), -- operator node - link to left child
 COL4 VARCHAR2(4000), -- operator node - operand (e.g. AND)
 COL5 VARCHAR2(4000)  -- operator node - link to right child
 );
```

Comment: thanks for your input.will using 'connect by' be a performance bottleneck further down the road? I am expecting that the table may grow to max 50,000 records

Comment: Probably! Especially if you don't have any limit on how deep your trees can get. If you allow chains with hundreds of levels, I think a hierarchical query will get pretty slow.